# What's the best way to clear peer dependency warning of pixi plugins like pixi-scrollbox when using pixi.js-legacy?

Tags: javascript, npm, pixi.js

The project I'm working on uses `pixi.js-legacy` instead of `pixi.js` because the latter doesn't support canvas rendering. The plugins, `pixi-ease`, `pixi-scrollbox` and `pixi-viewport` are working smoothly, but npm shows these warnings.

```sh
npm WARN pixi-ease@3.0.7 requires a peer of pixi.js@>=4.6.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN pixi-scrollbox@2.3.0 requires a peer of pixi.js@>=6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN pixi-viewport@4.9.2 requires a peer of pixi.js@>=4.6.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

Using npm@7 instead of npm@6 clears these warnings, but I need to use npm@6 as it's a requirement. Installing `pixi.js` as a production dependency clears the warnings too, but I'm concerned it might result in some unknown side-effects. Is this a safe way of doing it?